# Error on conversion Objective C to swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avfoundation

My Objective C Code :

```
NSDictionary *rgbOutputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCMPixelFormat_32BGRA] forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];
[self.videoDataOutput setVideoSettings:rgbOutputSettings];
```

I tried a lot of times and it is still error.
This is how I tried.

Swift:

```
var rgbOutputSettings: [NSObject: AnyObject] = kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatKey as! AnyObject: Int(kCMPixelFormat_32BGRA)]
self.videoOutput = rgbOutputSettings
```

Error: Could not find an overload for "int.init" that accepts the supplied arguments

Comment: What error you are getting ? Please add the error message to your question

Comment: @Midhun Sir I've added the error message on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var rgbOutputSettings = NSDictionary(objects: NSNumber(int: Int(kCMPixelFormat_32BGRA)), forKeys: kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey)
self.videoDataOutput.setVideoSettings(rgbOutputSettings)
```

Comment: I've created a layer for viewing video.
Swift Code:
previewLayer? = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)

Now the camera is visible.
But, How can I detect the face that appears on previewLayer using  AVMetaDataFaceObject?

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
videoOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]
```

Comment: @luk2302 Can I Use AVMetaDataFaceObject class to identify faces?

Comment: @Geniuz that is an entirely different question which I have no answer to.

Comment: @luk2302 I am trying to do like that way. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
let rgbOutputSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString :  NSNumber.init(unsignedInt: kCMPixelFormat_32BGRA)] as NSDictionary
self.videoOutput = rgbOutputSettings
```

Comment: NSNumber is not convertible to NSDictionary